# String datetime insert into mysql database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I am having following MySQL table

```
EventId     ObjectKey   Title           Description     When        Duration        Where           Status
INT         CHAR(36)    VARCHAR(500)    VARCHAR(8000)   DATETIME    VARCHAR(500)    VARCHAR(500)    TINYINT
```

and my PHP array is

```
$data = array(
    'Title' => $title,
    'Description' => $description,
    'When' => $when,
    'Duration' => $duration,
    'Where' => $where
);
```

The variable `$when` contains `02/21/2013`. When I try to insert to the table with CodeIgniter

```
public function insert_event($guid, $data)
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->load->database('default');
    $CI->db->set($data);
    $CI->db->set('ObjectKey', $guid);
    $CI->db->set('Status', 1);
    $vari = $CI->db->insert('Events');
    return $vari;
}
```

Everything inserted correctly except `date`. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the correct MYSQL format for the date `YYYY-MM-DD`. For example change this in your code:

```
$data = array(
    'Title' => $title,
    'Description' => $description,
    'When' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($when)),
    'Duration' => $duration,
    'Where' => $where
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Dates in mySQL are `YYYY-MM-DD`

You are inserting a date `MM/DD/YYYY`

So try this:

```
$data = array(
    'Title' => $title,
    'Description' => $description,
    'When' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($when)),
    'Duration' => $duration,
    'Where' => $where
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to store string date in any format in mysql

```
$srcFormat = "m/d/Y"; //convert string to php date
$destFormat = "Y-m-d" //convert php date to mysql date string

$data = array(
  'Title' => $title,
  'Description' => $description,
  'When' => DateTime::createFromFormat($srcFormat, $when)->format($destFormat),
  'Duration' => $duration,
  'Where' => $where
);
```